# submit select option value

Tags: jquery, jsp

How to submit select option value? I've got such form

```
 <form action="MakeResponseAction.do" method="POST" id="form-response">
        <fieldset>
           <select id="re" name="requestid">
                <c:forEach items="${requests}" var="requests">
                    <option value="${requests.id}">${requests.id}</option>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
             <input type="text" id="classId" name="classId" readonly>
             <input type="text" id="beds" name="beds" readonly> 
             <input type="text"  id="days" name="days" readonly/>  
             <input type="text" id="fio" name="fio" readonly>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

But when I submit it with

```
$("#form-response").submit();
```

It does not send option value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution

```
$("#form-response").get(0).submit();
```